# Are there any one-way operations that could be used for Diffie-Hellman post-quantum? (See criteria)

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, post-quantum-cryptography, one-way-function

With quantum-computers looming, there is a need for Public Key Cryptosystems that can withstand attacks by quantum-computers. Are there any known one-way operations that fit the following criteria?

- Is of course, one-way (you can only do f(x)=y and compute y, but not compute x knowing y),
- Can run on today's computers efficiently,
- Does not rely on the 'Integer Factorization Problem' or 'Discrete Logarithm Problem' (The two problems that almost all modern asymmetric ciphers rely on, could be broken with a quantum-computer running 'Shor's Algorithm')
- Is non-dependent on order, eg. satisfies f<sub>b</sub>(f<sub>a</sub>(x))=f<sub>a</sub>(f<sub>b</sub>(x)).

A one-way operation that follows this criteria could be used in a Diffie-Hellman style key agreement/exchange that is quantum-resistant.

Comment: Yes.  See the NIST PQCRYPTO competition for a menagerie of examples.  Most of them are based on learning with errors or on isogenies of supersingular elliptic curves.

Comment: Well the closest thing would be SIDH, which is actually Diffie-Hellman using supersingular isogenies.

Comment: Depending on your definition of one-wayness, this could be trivial and not enough to do diffie hellman, for example f(x)=0. You also need some min-entropy in the output to be able to use it as a key afterwards